# Django Template extensions

Tags: python, html, css, django

Probably a super easy thing to tackle but I have a template for a web page and that template has some common CSS that is linked at the surface.

```
<html>
{% load static %}
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'css/index.css' %}">
....

*navbar code in body
{%block content%}{%endblock%}
</html>
```

for any extending html pages they will have this layout plus some other personalized css. How can I add more custom CSS from a static folder without overriding the current CSS?

```
{% extends "template.html" %}
{% load static %}

?Insert custom css for the specific page?

{% block content %}
*CONTENT*
{%blockend%}
```

Comment: Make another block for the CSS, that is the whole point of template inheritacne.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use template blocks (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/templates/).

Base template (`template.html`):

```
{% load static %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'css/index.css' %}">
        {% block extra_css %}{% endblock %}
    </head>
...
```

Child template:

```
{% extends "template.html" %}
{% load static %}

{% block extra_css %}
   <!-- Specific template css here -->
   <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'css/another.css' %}">
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: Simple enough! Thanks great suggestion